# Can a SessionID be used to access Identity Service

Tags: rest-api, authentication, identity

Background:

oAuth 2.0 implemented on a public VF page and is working fine

1. User logs in - regular oAuth flow
2. Usual results returned including the instance url and id url

What I am curious about is

> If I pass a session Id to the page, is there a way to access the same information: instance_url, identity url?

I tried setting the `grant_type` to *password* as outlined here

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm

> /** For session ID instead of OAuth 2.0, use "grant_type", "password" **/

but I think that the comment is either incorrect or taken out of context as it did not work (as I thought)

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "authentication failure"
}
```

I am thinking there is not a way to use the session Id to get the Identity URL since the user did not grant permission to the connected app to access it and the sessionId is not a grant of permission, but maybe I am missing something.

Simply trying to bypass the need for the user to have to login and go through the oAuth flow, since I would have a valid session Id. But I need to access the identity service to get the org URLs and user information for the project to work.